# Pass a nested object to POST request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

How can I send a nested object via POST request?

```
var name = "test",
    path = "?diffCurr%5B%5D=FALSE&diffProv%5B%5D=FALSE",
    data = {
        datatype:"report",
        "value":{
                "name":name,
                "query":path
            }
        };

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "resources/savedata.html",
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
                    ...
        },
        complete: function(){
                    ...
        }
    })
```

When I check in the chrome, in the network tab under "form data", I see this:

```
datatype:report
value[name]:test
value[query]:?diffCurr%5B%5D=FALSE&diffProv%5B%5D=FALSE
```

Basically, I was expecting `$_POST["value"]` to contain an object with `name` and `query`.

Comment: POSTs by default in PHP just work as key-value pairs. If you want more functionality from them, you'll have to implement that yourself or find a library that's already done that. I would say it looks like the data is being sent and received properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, I was expecting $_POST["value"] to contain an object with name and query.

It does.

You are just looking at the raw data which is encoded in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with PHP's square bracket syntax for complex objects.

When PHP deserializes it to populate `$_POST`, it will do so in the form you expect.

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually not using PHP, but something inspired to it. I wanted to make sure I haven't to do anything on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way is serializing in a Json string your nested object

```
 $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "resources/savedata.html",

    data: JSON.stringify(data),

    success: function(data){
                ...
    },
    complete: function(){
                ...
    }
```